# How to access page sources from chrome devtools API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, nightmare

What is the easy way to access with the chrome devtools api all the content of the sources tab in the devtools?

I am writing a small program using nightmarejs to scrap some webpages. And I need to do some analysis, both on the rendered html and on the original one.

Nightmarejs doesn't provide an api call to get the source of the page. I am thinking about using the devtools api. But this is not clear to me how to do so. As I can see many files in the Sources tab of the chrome devtools, I thought I could get this content easily.

For now, I have a few leads:

1. The chrome.devtools.network API.

   There is snippet on the documentation:

   ```
   chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
       function(request) {
         if (request.response.bodySize > 40*1024) {
           chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
               'console.log("Large image: " + unescape("' +
               escape(request.request.url) + '"))');
         }
   });
   ```

   I thin I could use a listener like this. And get the body if it's available in the response. But I don't find the documentation for this response content. Also, I don't want to store the result of all the requests.
   But my main problem is that I don't see the content of the request here. I tried to do a request.getContent(), which returned me null.
2. chrome.debug

   I didn't have time to play with it yet.

Comment: chrome.debugger + [Network.getResponseBody](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Network/#method-getResponseBody). See the docs and other extensions that use it.